# How to populate torch::tensor with c++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen, tensor, libtorch

This is very basic: I am normally using Eigen3 for my math operations, but need to use libtorch for a network forward pass. Now I want to populate the `torch::tensor` with the data from my Eigen3 (or pure C++ `array`), but without a `for` loop. How can I do this?

Here is the solution with a loop:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1> inputEigen;  // previously initialized

torch::Tensor inputTorch = torch::ones({1, N});  // my torch tensor for the forward pass
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  inputTorch[0][i] = inputEigen[i];  // batch size == 1
}

std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
inputs.push_back(inputTorch);
at::Tensor output = net.forward(inputs).toTensor();
```

This works fine for now, but `N` might become really large and I'm just looking for a way to directly set the underlying data of my `torch::tensor` with a previously used C++ `array`

Comment: This might help: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/passing-stl-container-to-torch-tensors/36614

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Libtorch provides the `torch::from_blob` function (see [this thread](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12506)), which asks for a `void*` pointer to some data and an `IntArrayRef` to know the dimensions of the interpreted data. So that would give something like:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1> inputEigen; // previously initialized;
torch::Tensor inputElement = torch::from_blob(inputEigen.data(), {1,N}).clone();             // dims
```

Please note the call to `clone` which you may or may not need depending or your use case : basically `from_blob` does not take ownership of the underlying data, so without the clone it will remain shared with (and possibly destroyed by) your Eigen matrix